# Using csvWriter.writeRecords() to update a column is rendering all other columns blank

Tags: javascript

I am looping through a CSV file, and for each record, I want to write a value to the "Fruit" column.
I am using the writeRecords() method to do so. While my code is in fact writing values to the "Fruit" column, it appears to simultaneously be erasing the preexisting values under every other column.

Here's the relevant code snippets:

`````
`
const rows = [];
fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
    console.log(row);
    rows.push(row);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    const nextRow = getNextRow();
    if (nextRow) {
      processRow(nextRow);
    } else {
      console.log('All rows have been processed');
    }
  });

  function getNextRow() {
    // This function returns the next row to process, or null if all rows have been processed
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      return rows.shift();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }



async function processRow(row) {
  try {
    const itemID = row['ITEM ID'];
    const fruitArray = await getFruit(itemID);

    updatedRows.push(updateFruitInRow(row, rowUpdatedWithFruit));
 
    const nextRow = getNextRow();
    if (nextRow) {
      await processRow(nextRow);
    } else {
      console.log('All rows have been processed');
      // write all the updated records to the CSV file
      await csvWriter.writeRecords(updatedRows);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}



function updateFruitInRow(row, fruit) {
  const newRow = {};
  for (const columnName of header) {
    newRow[columnName] = row[columnName];
  }
  newRow.Fruit = fruit.join(', ');
  return newRow;
}

`

````

I believe the issue is with the writeRecords() function. I have tried collecting each row object in an array and then passing that array to `writeRecords()` after the file is done iterating.
`````